# Symfony 2.6 authentication with third party cookie or login form

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, authentication

I'm struggling with the security components of symfony. I want to achieve an authentication, based on a third party cookie and/or a traditional login form.
A little more in detail:
First of all the application should check if the user has a cookie from an other application in our environment. In this case the app recognizes the cookie,
validates it against an external api and the user is authenticated, if the session in the external api is valid. If it is not valid or the user has not such cookie the application forwards the request to the normal login form.
I already tried a lot ways to implement this behaviour, beginning with a custom login form authentication provider, through custom listeners, etc.

Currently I'm trying it with two separated security factories. One implements SecurityFactoryInterface with custom listener and provider and the other one
extends FormLoginFactory with a custom provider and the default listener.

Here some sample code from the current state:

CustomCookieSecurityFactory.php

```
class CustomCookieSecurityFactory implements SecurityFactoryInterface
{
  public function create(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config, $userProvider, $defaultEntryPoint)
  {
    $providerId = 'security.authentication.provider.custom.cookie.'.$id;
    $container
        ->setDefinition($providerId, new DefinitionDecorator('security.authentication.provider.custom.cookie'))
        ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProvider))
    ;

    $listenerId = 'security.authentication.listener.custom.cookie.'.$id;
    $listener = $container->setDefinition($listenerId, new DefinitionDecorator('security.authentication.listener.custom.cookie'));

    return array($providerId, $listenerId, $defaultEntryPoint);
  }

  public function getPosition()
  {
    return 'pre_auth';
  }

  public function getKey() {
    return 'custom_cookie';
  }
}
```

CustomFormLoginSecurityFactory

```
class CustomFormLoginSecurityFactory extends FormLoginFactory
{
  public function getKey()
  {
    return 'custom_form_login';
  }

  /**
   * Create custom provider.
   *
   */
  protected function createAuthProvider(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config, $userProviderId)
  {
    $provider = 'security.authentication.provider.custom.form.'.$id;
    $container
    ->setDefinition($provider, new DefinitionDecorator('security.authentication.provider.custom.form'))
    ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProviderId))
    ->replaceArgument(2, $id)
    ;

    return $provider;
  }
}
```

service.yml

```
security.authentication.listener.custom.cookie:
    class: AppBundle\Security\Http\Firewall\CustomCookieAuthenticationListener
    arguments: ["@security.token_storage", "@security.authentication.manager", "@service_container", "@logger"]

security.authentication.provider.custom.cookie:
    class: AppBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\CustomCookieAuthenticationProvider
    arguments: ["", "@logger"]

security.authentication.provider.custom.form:
    class: AppBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\CustomFormLoginAuthenticationProvider
    arguments: ["", "@security.user_checker", "", "@security.encoder_factory", true, "@logger", "@custom_router", "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@request_stack"]
```

security.yml

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        anonymous: ~
        custom_cookie: ~
        custom_form_login:
            provider: custom_user
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login-check
            username_parameter: form[username]
            password_parameter: form[password]
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
```

My main problem is, if the cookie based authentication does not work, the second type of authentication is not invoked. Maybe I'm on the completely wrong way or have just not configured my firewall correctly.

Would be good to have some help from someone knowing good symfony's security components.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html#storing-authentication-in-the-session) you can use `simple_preauth` parameter into your `security.yml` :

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/admin
            stateless: false
            simple_preauth:
                authenticator: apikey_authenticator
            provider: api_key_user_provider

    providers:
        api_key_user_provider:
            id: api_key_user_provider
```

You can also [chain providers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/multiple_user_providers.html) .